# Swift - Efficient Number to Character Conversion

Tags: swift, performance, data-conversion

If I have a long range of numbers such as 1...1000000, what would be an efficient way to convert them to strings with the following mapping?

1->A, 2->B, 3->C, ... 10->A0, 11->AA, 12->AB etc.

I took the approach of splitting each number into digits (using modulus) and using it to get a character from an array to build the strings. Takes about 5 seconds for 1...1000. Is there a faster approach?

My code:

```
let numbers = 1...1000000
let charArray:[Character] = ["0","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
var results: [String] = []

func transformNumbers() {
    for number in numbers {
        var string = ""
        var i = number
        while i > 0 {string.insert(charArray[(i%10)], at: string.startIndex); i/=10}
        results.append(string)
    }
}
```

Comment: _Takes about 5 seconds for 1...1000_ seems to be too long. _for 1...1000000` as in the first line?

Comment: Is the `numbers` array in order?

Comment: You could try to convert the number into a string of digits. Then using `replacingOccurances()`, replace every '1' with an 'A' ('2' with 'B', etc.). See if the performance improves.

Comment: I'm running it in a playground on a 3-year-old core i7 macbook air. It's definitely for the 1...1000 and not 1...1000000. The numbers array is in order.

Comment: Playground is not a good place to test performance. It checks many intermediate results and tries to show them (as you see many **... times** ), the behavior is far from the code in actual apps. Create a simple project (macOS Command Line Tool, for example) and run it.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll test them outside playground. AgRizzo: I tried that but the performance stayed the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code took about 15 seconds on my old MacBook for `1...1000000`, and the code below, less than 1 second:

(Using Xcode 8.3.3 with Release build on macOS 10.12.5)

```
let unicodeScalarArray:[UnicodeScalar] = ["0","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
let utf16CodeUnitArray:[UInt16] = unicodeScalarArray.map{UInt16($0.value)}
var results: [String] = []

func transformNumbers7() {
    results = numbers.map {number in
        var digits: [UInt16] = []
        var i = number
        while i > 0 {digits.append(utf16CodeUnitArray[i%10]); i/=10}
        digits.reverse()
        return String(utf16CodeUnits: digits, count: digits.count)
    }
}
```

Generally,

- Repeated `insert(_:at:)` can be slower than repeated `append(_:)` and `reverse()`
- Working with `Character`s may be less efficient than `UnicodeScalar`, UTF-16 Code Units or UTF-8 Code Units.

Comment: This resulted in a 2x increase on my machine in a compiled project. The biggest difference appears to have come from append+reverse. Thanks!

Comment: @RomanSheydvasser, maybe **_2x_** is found with Debug build. With Release build, the difference would be bigger. Please try.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the fastest way, but switching to a `map` expression instead of mutating the results list speeds things up a bit over 10x on my machine:

```
let results = numbers.map { (val: Int) -> String in
    var string = ""
    var i = val
    while i > 0 {string.insert(charArray[(i%10)], at: string.startIndex); i/=10}
    return string
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! I saw a similar 10x increase on my machine in playground and faster than OOPer's code, but after running it in a compiled project, it actually ended up being slightly slower than my original code. I guess environment makes a big difference. In any case I appreciate the tip about the map expression.